# Is there an altitude measurement that would be negative with 5 digits and 10 decimals?

Tags: altitude

We received a data file that has altitude listed, but the format is unexpected.  Here is the format:

`-######.##########`

Is there any altitude measurement like this? Or is this possibly a conversion gone wrong?

Comment: Have you asked whomever you received it from?

Comment: Even a scanning electron microscope isn't going to report coordinates to the [covalent radius of a sulfur atom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orders_of_magnitude_(length)#100_picometres) (in meters). Ob-xkcd https://xkcd.com/2170/

Comment: Could be a nodata value but it's unusual to use decimal and all nodata value should have the same value...

Comment: Could it be just a unit and/or reference problem like an altitude relative to some reference point and expressed in millimeter. If so the only person able to answer your question is the data producer